# Exposing Collection<Something> from ManagedResource bean?

Tags: java, spring, jmx, mbeans, spring-jmx

```
@ManagedResource
@Component
public class MyBean {
   Map<String, Something> map = new HashMap<String, Something>();

   @ManagedAttribute
   public Collection<Something> getFoo() {
       return map.values();
   }
}
```

The foo attributed shows as 'unavailable' in the visualvm mbeans tab. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I annotated the bean with @MXBean then returned CompositeData[] creating instances of CompositeDataSupport.

Answer (score 3):

The MXBean solution is the way to go most of the time, although there is a slightly easier way than generating CompositeDataSupport instances. Let's say your class is:

```
public class Something {
  private String foo;
  private Date date;
  <Insert Ctor here>
  public String getFoo() {
    return foo;
  }
  public Date getDate() {
    return date;
  }
}
```

You can create an MBean interface as follows:

```
public interface SomethingMBean {  // same package please...
  public String getFoo();
  public Date getDate();
}
```

Make Something implement SomethingMBean:

```
public class Something implements SomethingMBean {
   .....
}
```

Now in your actual MBean (the @MXBean annotated one), you can define a method like this:

```
   public List<SomethingMBean> getSomethings() {
      .....
   }
```

The Java6+ MBeanServer will automatically generate CompositeDataTypes and instances at runtime. As a simple diagnostic tool, I frequently swap out the JVM's [ThreadMXBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html) with a wrapped one that exposes [ThreadInfo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadInfo.html)s using this technique. (See [ExtendedThreadManager](https://github.com/nickman/apmrouter/blob/master/apmrouter-agent/src/main/java/org/helios/apmrouter/jmx/threadinfo/ExtendedThreadManager.java) for an example) It looks like this in JConsole:

[image: ThreadInfos exposed in JConsole]

Comment: Does the interface name must end with MBean?

Answer (score 1):

It will work if `Something` is part of the JDK (such as String).

If `Something` is a custom class, VisualVM won't know about it; hence 'unavailable'.

You can see more information if you go to the `operations` tab and click `getFoo()`.

I have not tried it, but I believe you can add stuff to VisualVM's class path with

```
jvisualvm -cp:a /path/to/Something/top/level/package
```

(or jar).

Then, it might work; even then, though, `Something` (and its fields) needs to be `Serializable`.

Comment: So how can I display something that is not part of the JDK?